# Adding upon previous value(java)?

Tags: java, math

I have a grocery list and based upon the values the user gives me I have to update the total. For instance:

[image]

As you might have noticed the total is updated every time, how do I do that in my code?

This is what I have:

```
public class CalcGroceryList {
private double productOne;
private double productTwo;
private double productThree;
private double productFour;
private double productFive;
private int n++;

public CalcGroceryList(){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter price of first item:");
    productOne = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter price of second item:");
    productTwo = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter price of third item:");
    productThree = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter price of fourth item:");
    productFour = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter price of fifth item:");
    productFive = in.nextDouble();
}

public double calc(){
    return productOne + productTwo + productThree + productFour + productFive;
}

public void printResults(){
    System.out.printf("%10s %10s %10s \n", "Item:", "Cost:", "Price:");
    System.out.printf("%10d %10.2f %10.2f \n", n++ ,productOne, productOne);
    System.out.printf("%10d %10.2f %10.2f", n++ ,productTwo, productTwo + productOne);  
}
```

}

```
System.out.printf("%10d %10.2f %10.2f", n++ ,productTwo, productTwo + productOne);
```

As you  see here I simply added the two values (productTwo + productOne) but is there a way I can do this without specifying the exact values, so for example each time add all the current values that we have.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `total = 0;`, `total += productOne;`, `total += productTwo;` and so on?  The `+=` operator adds the value on the right to the variable on the left and reassigns the variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter price of first item:");
    product = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter price of second item:");
    product += in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter price of third item:");
    product += in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter price of fourth item:");
    product += in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter price of fifth item:");
    product += in.nextDouble();
```

there are better ways, but just making what you currently have easier would be something like this.

Comment: That wouldn't be a good way to do it because you couldn't use the individual values later on.

Comment: why would I do that, that would just make me loose each one of their specific values.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create a variable to hold the total value of the items and every time the user adds a value to the list it uses the **+=** operator to add to the total. Eg:

```
private double total;
```

Adding to the total:

```
System.out.println("Enter price of second item:");
productTwo = in.nextDouble();
total += productTwo;
//call a method here to print the values to the table
```

For printing the value:

```
System.out.printf("%10d %10.2f %10.2f", n++ ,productTwo, total);
```

Comment: It was a mistake. Edited it though.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this using an `ArrayList`

```
ArrayList<Double> costArray = new ArrayList<Double>();
double cost;

System.out.println("Enter price of first item:");
cost = in.nextDouble();
costArray.add(cost);
System.out.println("Enter price of second item:");
cost = in.nextDouble();
costArray.add(cost);
System.out.println("Enter price of third item:");
cost = in.nextDouble();
costArray.add(cost);
System.out.println("Enter price of fourth item:");
cost = in.nextDouble()
costArray.add(cost);
System.out.println("Enter price of fifth item:");
product += in.nextDouble();
costArray.add(cost);

double total = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= costArray.length; i++) {
    total += costArray[i];
    System.out.printf("%10s %10.2f %10.2f", "#" + i, costArray[i], total);
}
```

`total += costArray[i]` is the same as `total = total + castArray[i]`.